# Finding duplicates in an array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find duplicates in a sorted array of objects with a Name property. I have the following code:

```
for (($i -eq 1), ($i -lt $arr.Length), ($i++))
{
    if($arr[$i] -eq $arr[$i-1])
    {
        write-host "Duplicates found: " $arr[$i].Name, $arr[$i-1].Name
    }
}
```

If the Name property is the same as the one in the array before it, it should in theory return the name of the duplicate. However, it's just infinitely looping and printing the name of a random object over and over. What do?

Comment: `$i -eq 1` will make it loop indefinitely, you want to do `$i = 1` (assignment). But whats the particular reason of doing this? there are easier ways to find Duplicates in an array, such as `Group-Object`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this without looping using `Compare-Object`

To demonstrate, in `$a` I have your array of objects, sorted on property Name:

```
$a = @'
Name,SomeValue
foo,1
bar,2
baz,3
bar,4
foo,5
bar,6
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | Sort-Object Name
```

To output the duplicates you can then do

```
$b = $a | Select-Object Name -Unique
Compare-Object -Property Name -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b -PassThru | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator
```

Giving you this as result:

```
Name SomeValue
---- ---------
bar  4        
bar  6        
foo  5
```

The same can be achieved using `Group-Object` and a ForEach-Object loop:

```
$a | Group-Object Name | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Select-Object -Skip 1
}
```